# Laravel Eloquent to get relational table data by one column as a key and another as value

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have two tables `users` and `user_profiles` with the following schema

### Users Table

- id
- username
- email
- password
- role
- is_root
- created_at
- updated_at

### User Profiles Table

- id
- user_id (FK -> users -> id)
- key
- value

## User Modal

```
public function profileData()
{
    return $this->hasMany(UserProfile::class);
}
```

## UserProfile Modal

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

So if I use `$user->profileData` it is giving me this result, which is correct.

```
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3244
     all: [
       App\UserProfile {#3251
         id: 3,
         user_id: 10,
         key: "country",
         value: "India",
       },
       App\UserProfile {#3242
         id: 1,
         user_id: 10,
         key: "first_name",
         value: "John",
       },
       App\UserProfile {#3252
         id: 2,
         user_id: 10,
         key: "last_name",
         value: "Doe",
       },
     ],
   }
```

> #### Question
>
> However, I wan to fetch the `value` field's value/data from the `user_profiles` table by providing the `key` fields value by
>   user id. For instance, if I pass the `country` it should return
>   `India` or `first_name` then `John` in the above example. How to
>   achieve that?

Comment: `$countries = UserProfile::where('user_id', $id)->select(['key','value'])->get()->toArray()`

Comment: @BohdanPetrenko thanks a lot for the reply. Probably I haven't explained it well. What I am looking for is one item by key. So if I pass `country` it should return `India` etc.

Comment: `$user->profileData->firstWhere('key', $key)->value` or $user->profileData()->where('key', $key)->first()->value`

Comment: Great but it returns regardless of user id. How to pass user id?

Comment: `UserProfile::where('user_id', $id)->where('key', $key)->first()->vallue`

Comment: I think it is giving by user id but if the field is not set than giving error `Trying to get property 'value' of non-object` is there any way ignore if no data?

Comment: try this `UserProfile::where('user_id', $id)->where('key', $key)->value('value')`

Comment: I think the problem is not that. The problem is if the user hasn't set that field the record won't be available. In that case, it is giving error.

Comment: `UserProfile::where('user_id', $id)->where('key', $key)->select(['key','value'])->value('value')`

Comment: @BohdanPetrenko amazing. fixed the issue. Please post it as an answer so I can select it. Thank you very much... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U need to use `where()`, `select()` and `value()` statement for needed value

```
UserProfile::where('user_id', $id)->where('key', $key)->select(['key','value'])->value('value')
```